# Stop motion movie with iMovie11

Tags: imovie

How can I make a stop motion movie with iMovie.
I just want to play around, so I don't want to buy [iStopMotion](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/3841/stop-motion-movie).
All tutorials I've found are with iMovie09 or older. 
I have some 50 pictures in a folder, that I d'like to use for that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a really cool video tutorial on YouTube that shows you how to make stop motion movies with iMovie 11 from photos in your iPhoto library (although can be any folder source).

Check it out [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ioo4omMVNbM).

Hope this helps.