# Automating Quicktime Image Sequence creation in Mountain Lion

Tags: quicktime

I have 69 folders of jpegs I want to turn into 69 quicktime timelapse movies.  Rather than doing this one-at-a-time in Quicktime 7 Pro (Open Image Sequence, select first frame, choose 30 fps as the frame rate, wait for frames to assemble, save result while selecting "as reference movie", change the name of the resulting Quicktime from "Untitled.mov" to the corresponding jpeg folder name, repeat) -- is there an easy way to automate this?

Comment: Would http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/13385/stop-motion-movie-with-imovie11 be an option?

Comment: I think iMovie would re-compress to a smaller resolution.  I prefer to stick to QuickTime Pro and stay full rez.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Automator with some AppleScript will do this nicely. The frames need to be named consistently — `blah1.jpg blah2.jpg blah3.jpg … blah50.jpg` etc. Each sequence you want to be a movie should be in its own folder.

1. Open **Automator** and create a new workflow.
2. Add the **Get Specified Finder Items** action and add each folder containing the sequences to the action.
3. Add the **Run AppleScript** action, with the following code:

   ```
   on run {input, parameters}
       repeat with theFolder in input
           tell application "Finder" to set theSequence to first item of folder theFolder as alias
           tell application "QuickTime Player 7"
               activate
               open image sequence theSequence frames per second 30

               set nameSequence to (theSequence as string) & ".mov"

               tell document 1
                   with timeout of 500 seconds
                       save self contained in nameSequence
                   end timeout

               end tell
           end tell
       end repeat
   end run
   ```

Run it, and you'll get a `.mov` in each folder. Let me know if you have any questions.

The AppleScript code is adapted from [this post](http://hintsforums.macworld.com/showpost.php?p=336977&postcount=3) at the Macworld Hints forum.

Comment: Thanks!  Changed "save self contained in nameSequence" to "save in nameSequence" in order to save as QuickTime reference movie.

Comment: Here's the resulting video posted to YouTube: http://bit.ly/QXrstl

Comment: I tried your script and works perfect! Do you know how to change the compression settings to the same script, in order to use an Apple Prores for example? Otherwise works perfectly well, but it compress it as a Photojpeg codec. Thank you very much for the post

Comment: I don't know.  I guess you could use MPEGStreamclip or Apple's Compressor to batch encode your photojpegs into Prores.